# Kubuntu 14.04 does not unlock the screen

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, acer

I installed Kubuntu 14.04 on my Acer Aspire E1-431-2896, this installation took place normally with the default installation of updates.

The problem is occurring in my everyday use, when the notebook is a certain idle time the system naturally enters power saving and suspends the session for Ram Memory, which usually always happened in other versions of Kubuntu, the problem in 14.04 occurs when I try to use it again.

In 14.04 after entering suspend mode it no longer returns to the desktop, when I click or use the mouse sometimes the login box does not appear and, when present, directs me to a screen that has only the default Kubuntu image as wallpaper wall, where I can not go out or perform some action.

Commands such as Ctrl + Esc, Enter, Alt + F1, have no effect and whenever this happens I need to reboot the machine using the physical button.